# CSV file not open in IE

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have create a CSV file in my php code,
after create CSV, I try to open the CSV using window.open(),
this will work fine all browser except IE 7 and IE 8,

in IE a new window open then it close automatically

how to solve this problem,

Comment: what do you set the headers to?

Comment: i'm not set any thing in header

Comment: Are IE perhaps downloading the csv instead of displaying?

Comment: Show us. Or are we supposed to be psychic?

Comment: are you sending `header("Content-type: text/cvs");` ?

Comment: Please edit the question to share your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall, Internet Explorer has a peculiar quirk when trying to open files, even if the proper MIME type is set in the header.

You may need to do the following to get the CSV to download:

- Go to `Tools` > `Internet Options`
- Select the `Security` tab, then press the `Custom Level...` button
- Scroll down to the `Downloads` section, and under `Automatic prompting for file downloads` select `Enable`

Hopefully, that should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following at the beginning of your script:

```
header('Content-Disposition:inline');
```

This should direct the browser to display the file instead of prompting a download, which may be the problem.